# Lose "modern" (CSS3) styles when viewing on IIS vs VS Development Server

Tags: css, visual-studio, iis

When I F5 using the Visual Studio development server (`http://localhost:XXXX/application`) all styles look fine.  When I F5 using local IIS (`http://localhost/application`), styles *still* look fine.  However, now, if I try to navigate to `http://pc-name/application` directly from the browser, I lose the modern CSS styles (i.e., rounded corners, opacity, etc...), while all other CSS and layout remains the same.

I'm using IIS v7.5.7600.16385

Comment: What browser? Are you in IE compatibility mode?

Comment: IE 10... It does look more normal in Chrome.  And I'm not sure if I'm in compatibility mode, I don't believe so.. but possibly

Comment: Correction... I was in compatibility mode for Intranet sites (this site).  This resolved the issue.  Thanks

Comment: Not sure why this is closed as "too localized..."  CSS styles not rendering between one environment and another due to a default setting in IE doesn't sound like I'll be the only one to ever encounter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if you're in compatibility mode.

Check your internet settings.

Comment: To add to this.  IE defaults to use Compatibility Mode for intranet sites.  An option is not to have all users uncheck this.  There is, however, an override with meta tags