# Visual Studio Development Server - CSS is lost. On IIS Server is working

Tags: .net, css, iis, aspnet-development-server

When I'm using `Visual Studio Development Server` (`http://localhost:64217/application`) `CSS` gets lost and `Chrome` is showing the following warnings and errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

When using `IIS server` (`http://localhost/application`) the styles are fine.

I've checked these duplicate questions [Visual Studio Development Server not updating css and javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1563648/1479895) and [Lose “modern” (CSS3) styles when viewing on IIS vs VS Development Server [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319518/lose-modern-css3-styles-when-viewing-on-iis-vs-vs-development-server). Unfortunately none of them helped me.

I've tried clearing the cache and also didn't help.
Any guesses what might cause this to happen are very appreciated.

Also I have to mention that this happened today. Back in the past I was using both `IIS` and `Development Server` and I didn't have this problem.

**EDIT**

I'm using `Jquery Mobile` and I've included the `JQM CSS` in the master page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" runat="server" />
```

All the other `CSS` files are included in `App_Themes/Default` and included in the `web.config`:

```
<pages theme="Default" />
```

Comment: You are missing `type="text/css"` on the `<link>`. The correct declaration is: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" runat="server" type="text/css" />`

Comment: why would you even need `runat="server"` on that? (/cc @Caelea)

Comment: The "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html" message suggests the browser is returning html instead of css... so: what *do* you get if you navigate to the css url? A yellow screen of death, perhaps?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm getting normal row html page without css. I found the error in the Error Log in Chrome. About the `runat="server"` - I've googled the error and there were some suggestions to include `runat="server"` but still doesn't work.

Comment: @Caelea I've copied the include reference from the JQuery Mobile web-site. I've just added `runat="server"`. Anyway I've tried your suggestion, but still doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you try to copy the jQuery Mobile CSS into a local folder of your web app and see if it's loading?

Comment: @Andreaoid no, I've not tried it, since I'm already using themes and the css/imgs which are in the project are not showing(not only the JQM CSS) - why even trying to copy the JQuery Mobile CSS.

Comment: Do you have any reference to the port you're using? It happened to me in the past that VS changes the port - when it's busy or for other reasons - (64217 in your case) and my old references to the old port didn't work anymore.